copy and paste range to range
I'm trying to create a form and have a new part button. If I click new part then I want rows 13-33 and button to be copied and pasted below to create a new for another part.
I've had success to coping to another sheet but not within the sheet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
